# How do I make a dmsetup change permanent?

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, iscsi, datastore

The full case is the following:

- I attach a LUN from a SAN box (iscsi configuration has been done correctly)
- As soon as I restart the open-iscsi daemon, the LUN is attached and its name appears under `/dev/mapper` is something like the following string: `360060e80104dac0004f349c800000001`

Now I don't want to use this alphanumeric, I need a decent mnemonic. So, I use the dmsetup command as follows:
`# dmsetup rename 360060e80104dac0004f349c800000001 datastore`

and a `datastore` link to a dm device appears under /dev/mapper. Problem solved, until the next reboot. where the `datastore` mnemonic is gone and the above alphanumeric appears again under /dev/mapper.

How do I make this change permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider referencing the LUN via `/dev/disk/by-{id,path,uuid}` instead of trying to rename WWN every time.

Or maybe you can make a udev(7) rule to create a static node under `/dev` representing your block device based on attributes related to your WWN. You can get all the attributes with udevadm(8). A good starting point would be `ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION`:

`ENV{ID_WWN_WITH_EXTENSION}=="360060e80104dac0004f349c800000001", SYMLINK+="iscsi/datastore"`

This creates a symlink at /dev/iscsi/datastore that points to your iscsi LUN.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dmsetup rename entry in `/etc/rc.local`

```
echo "dmsetup rename 360060e80104dac0004f349c800000001 datastore" >> /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the OS specifics. However, most modern OSes support udev and this is a pretty good way to do what you are trying.

After assigning the lun to the system, just get the scsi_id of the disk. You need to get the sg3_utils package installed. I am talking in Red Hat and derivative terms.

```
/sbin/scsi_id --page=0x83 --whitelisted /dev/sdX
```

Replace sdx with sda or sdb or whatever.

Now, that you have the scsi_id, write a udev rule in `/etc/udev/ruls.d` directory.

```
KERNEL="sd*", BUS=="SCSI", PROGRAM=="/sbin/scsi_id -gus /dev/sd*", RESULT=="XXXX", SYMLINK+="datastore", OWNER=="username", GROUP=="groupname", MODE="0664"
```

I came up with the rule from scratching my memory but the syntax should be correct.

Restart udev after this or better bet, reboot.

Comment: -gus for rhel5 and -gud for rhel6. scsi_id has got hell lot of switches, /sbin/scsi_id --page=0x83 gives the VPD data, --page=0x80 gives manufacturer data. Select what you want